# Next.JS e.preventDefault() not working (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, next.js, preventdefault

I'm using Next.JS with Typescript. The problem is that e.preventDefault() doesn't work, and my input gets cleared on submit.

```
  const ModalLatino = () => {
    const handleSubmitLatino = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const text = textAreaLatinoRef?.current?.value;
      if (text) {
        const notify = () => toast.success("Traduzione in corso...\nPotrebbe volerci fino a 1 minuto per tradurre il testo!");
        notify();
        setIsActiveButtonLatino(false);
        setDoTraduzioneLatino(text);
      } else {
        const notify = () => toast.error("Inserisci un testo!");
        notify();
      }
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto" aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
          <div className="flex items-end justify-center pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
            <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true"></div>
            <span className="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>
            <div className="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full w-full h-3/6" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-headline">
              <div className="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                <div className="">
                  <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
                    <div className="flex flex-row justify-between w-full">
                      <h3 className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900" id="modal-headline">
                        Traduttore di Latino
                      </h3>
                      <button className="cursor-pointer border rounded-sm p-0.5" onClick={() => setIsOpenedLatino(false)}>
                        <GrClose />
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmitLatino}>
                      <div className="mt-2 flex flex-row justify-center">
                        <input type="text" className="border w-9/12 mx-auto rounded-md" ref={textAreaLatinoRef} placeholder="Inserisci qui il testo da tradurre..." />
                      </div>
                      <div className="mt-2 flex flex-row justify-center">
                        <textarea className="border w-9/12 mx-auto rounded-md" placeholder="La traduzione apparirà qui..." disabled value={traduzioneLatino ?? null}></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex flex-row justify-center">
                        <button className="border rounded-md p-1 mt-5 mx-2.5" disabled={!isActiveButtonLatino} type="submit">Traduci</button>
                        <button className="border rounded-md p-1 mt-5 mx-2.5">Copia</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  };
```

That's my code. All seems good to me, but obviously there is something wrong. Please let me know!